# Where is the 'folder view' for RSS feeds in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, rss-reader

All,

I've switched from Google Reader to Thunderbird to read / manage RSS feeds.

For some reason, the folder view of my imported feeds does not show up in Thunderbird, yet in the 'manage subscriptions' panel, the folder hierarchy is preserved.

See the attached screen shot.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

[image: Thunderbird RSS folder issue]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a folder view for rss in Thunderbird.
You could install the Bamboo add-on but you might as well do that in Firefox.

Here's a workaround:

1. Right click on your rss folder
2. Search Messages...
3. Change the drop down box from "contains" to "doesn't contain"
4. Type a crazy word in the text field (I put "zigloo", pretty safe to assume that will never pop up in a rss feed, but you could go crazier)
5. Click on "Save as Search Folder"

You can then give it a name and put it where you want.

Comment: I think I'll just use the 'folder' in Thunderbird - once you have a folder, although it has the same icon as an RSS feed, it will still behave like a folder. The problem I have had here is that the OPML file from google reader when imported into firefox will not preserve the folder structure. I'll have to manually import a OPML of all my feeds, NOT In folders...Thank you all!!!

Answer (score 1):

.opml file with feeds is in Xml format, so you may put each leaf (*outline* element without sub-elements) in an artificial wrapper element, which will get a visible folder in Thunderbird. Thus your initial .opml file:

```
<opml version="1.0">
  <body>
    <outline text="Birds">
      <outline title="ParrotBlog" xmlUrl="http://parrot.com/feed"/>
    </outline>
  </body>
</opml>
```

should be converted to this:

```
<opml version="1.0">
  <body>
    <outline text="Birds">
      <outline text="ParrotBlog">
        <outline title="ParrotBlog" xmlUrl="http://parrot.com/feed"/>
      </outline>
    </outline>
  </body>
</opml>
```

You may use an on-line Xslt converter ([here](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html), [here](http://xslttest.appspot.com/)) to perform (xml+xslt)->xml. Use the Xsl transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="outline[not(child::*)]">
  <xsl:element name="outline">
      <xsl:attribute name="text"><xsl:value-of select="@title"/></xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>  
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/ | @* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>  
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This workaround may work for you, till you find a decent Feeds Aggregator.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by user63289 allowed me to import my feeds from QuiteRSS into Thunderbird, but I had to modify the XSL transformation slightly since my OPML file was in the following format:

```
<opml version="1.0">
  <body>
    <outline text="Birds">
      <outline text="ParrotBlog" xmlUrl="http://parrot.com/feed"/>
    </outline>
  </body>
</opml>
```

The only difference being the line that says "text=" instead of "title=". If you have this issue, you only have to modify the XSL transformation slightly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="outline[not(child::*)]">
  <xsl:element name="outline">
      <xsl:attribute name="text"><xsl:value-of select="@text"/></xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>  
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/ | @* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>  
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```